# Every third post pull from excluded category. WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I was hoping for some advice on the following.

On my homepage, I want to list all posts from all categories except one (category 11) and insert category 11 posts each third post.

e.g.

> POST 1 (Post from category '2')
>
> POST 2 (Post from category '7')
>
> **POST 3 (Post from '11')**
>
> POST 4 (Post from category '5')
>
> POST 5 (Post from category '7')
>
> **POST 6 (Post from '11')**
>
> POST 7 (Post from category '7')
>
> POST 8 (Post from category '1')
>
> **POST 9 (Post from '11')**

It all needs to live within while posts for pagination etc.

Could someone advise on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need [multiple loops](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops) to achieve this. You'll have to create another instance of `WP_Query` that will fetch the posts from category 11. And then, Loop through all of the other posts normally while counting and checking whether or not to show a post from category 11.

```
$page_query_var = 'page';
$post_cat_10 = new WP_Query('cat=10' . '&paged=' . get_query_var($page_query_var));
$other_posts = new WP_Query('cat=-10' . '&paged=' . get_query_var($page_query_var));
for ($i = 1; $other_posts->have_posts(); $i++)
{
    if ($i % 3 === 0 AND $post_cat_10->have_posts())
    {
        $post_cat_10->the_post();
    }
    else
    {
        $other_posts->the_post();
    }
    the_title();
    the_content();
}
```

Comment: Nice! would this still work with the standard wordpress pagination?

Comment: @user1315018 Yes, I believe so. You can check out the documentation for more detail if you want. http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters

Comment: it works for the cat 11 posts although i cannot output anything else.

Comment: @user1315018 See my edit. Also, for the pagination to work, you'll need to change `$page_query_var` accordingly to your own theme query for page number.

Comment: I see. Although when i set 'Blog pages show at most'  in the admin panel to 6 it still displays all of the posts (20 of them). Does this need to somehow be wrapped in while {??

Comment: You can limit the total number of post by adding `&posts_per_page=x` to the string that you pass into the `WP_Query` constructor with x being the limit of post to fetch for each query. You really should check out the documentation. It's pretty helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You simply just output every POST but the number in the array, that can be divided by 3. It might be easier to show to you:

```
<?php

//Make your SQL-statement within the $result variable

$i = 0;
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $i++;
    if( $i % 3 > 0) {
        $output[] = $row['COLUMN_NAME'];
    }
}

echo implode("<br>\n", $output);

?>
```

Comment: This is about `WordPress` not raw PHP.

Comment: I can see that on your answer - OP didn't mention that in his question.

Comment: Yes, I know. But he did put `wordpress` in the tags.

Comment: Oh yes, I missed that. My bad.